# Execute javascript function after the jQuery .load() content is fully ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal box that I populate with content that is loaded with ajax jQuery .load() function. The main problem is that I cant execute another function only after the ajax content, like: images, text etc., are fully loaded inside the hidden modal.

For example: I need to center the modal box depending on its width & height like this:

```
    var modalbox = $('.modalbox');

        function centermodal(a){                    

            overlayWidth = a.width(),
            overlayHeight = a.height();

            a.css({                     
                'margin-top':'-'+overlayHeight/2+'px',
                'margin-left':'-'+overlayWidth/2+'px'
            }); 

            a.show(); //show the box                    

        }
```

Then I execute this function inside the load but it wont calculate the correct height of the modal if it would contain images or any extra content:

```
modalbox.load('page1.html','',function(){
    centermodal(modalbox);
});
```

I believe I need to create some sort of the loader or make a check of loaded content before showing. Maybe someone could suggest a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object is the tool for this job. Use the [deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) function to call a function when the AJAX call is complete.